# How to stop ipfs daemon?(ctrl+c works only when you are inside daemon cmd prompt). Need solution to make it work from other cmd prompts as well

Tags: ipfs

Just got started with ipfs. 
after we do $ipfs daemon and then i reach out to localhost:5001/webui (which shows connection refused. checked proxy and evrything). The daemon escapes the cmd, but still running in background. 
when we do $ipfs swarm peers. it gives "error: api not running"

[click here to view the cmd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iic7v.png)

Answer (score 8):

On macOS/Unix it would be `killall ipfs`, so maybe the equivalent `taskkill` command should suffice on Windows, which would (probably! I don't know anything about Windows) be `taskkill /f /im ipfs`, but maybe you should test it first without the `/f` (force) option.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491009.aspx

As a sidenote: there's been some discussion in the ipfs realm about adding `start` and `stop` to the `ipfs daemon` command; but I don't know if and when it's going to be implemented.

It has been added; the command is `ipfs shutdown`